# Serialization error when deleting an item with Cosmo DB in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a big problem when I want to delete an item in Cosmo DB from my application in ASP.NET Core. I'm doing a simple CRUD to practice but I can't delete any records without getting the following error:

[image]

This is my class with the fields I'm using:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]

        public string id { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userNameChannel")]
        public string userNameChannel { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "channel")]
        public string channel { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "registerDate")]
        public DateTime registerDate { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phone")]
        public string phone { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fullName")]
        public string fullName { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
        public string email { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

And in my controller I am using the following to delete an item

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    try
    {
        var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_config["CosmosDB:DatabaseName"], _config["CosmosDB:ContainerName"]);
        var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = @id")
            .WithParameter("@id", id);

        var result = await container.GetItemQueryIterator<UserModel>(query).ReadNextAsync();
        var user = result.FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(user);
    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)ex.StatusCode, ex);
    }
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    try
    {
        var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_config["CosmosDB:DatabaseName"], _config["CosmosDB:ContainerName"]);

        var result = await container.DeleteItemAsync<UserModel>(id, new PartitionKey(id));

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)ex.StatusCode, ex);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me find the error or how I could fix it.

Comment: I tried executing code to delete document from Cosmos DB collection and able to achieve it without any error/exception. In posted code, you mentioned 2 delete method in controller where 1st one is fetching data not deleting the record. Also, can you check and confirm the `DeleteItemAsync` method is executing successfully. If yes, then I suspect there is an issue with your ActionMenthod named as "Index".

Comment: fyi - [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Which call is causing the exception (and please edit to contain properly formatted text for the exception)? Please provide all relevant debugging details, to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the serialization from the Delete all together (you are not consuming it anyway).

```
var result = await container.DeleteItemAsync<UserModel>(id, new PartitionKey(id), new ItemRequestOptions() { EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false });
```

`EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false` would avoid the body of the deleted item to be returned, save serialization and network time.

Reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/enable-content-response-on-write/

Going further, you could simply use `DeleteItemStreamAsync`:

```
try
{
    var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_config["CosmosDB:DatabaseName"], _config["CosmosDB:ContainerName"]);

    var result = await container.DeleteItemStreamAsync(id, new PartitionKey(id));

    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
catch (CosmosException ex)
{
    return StatusCode((int)ex.StatusCode, ex);
}
```